# Generic stack don't push or pop value

Tags: c, generics

I'm trying to implement generic stack in C, but I can't print value that I pushed. Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory.h>

typedef struct{
    void *elems;
    int sizeOfElems;
    int allocated;
    int lenght;
}stack;

void allocate_stack(stack *s, int sizeOfElements){
    assert(sizeOfElements > 0);
    s->sizeOfElems = sizeOfElements;
    s->allocated = 2;
    s->lenght = 2;
    s->elems = malloc(sizeOfElements * s->allocated);
}

void deallocate_stack(stack *s){
    free(s->elems);
}

void push_elem(stack *s, void *elem){
    s->lenght += 1;
    if(s->allocated == s->lenght){
        realloc(s, s->lenght * s->sizeOfElems);
        s->lenght *= 2;
    }
     void *target = (char *)s->elems + s->lenght * s->sizeOfElems;
     memcpy(target, elem, s->sizeOfElems);
}
void pop_elem(stack *s, void *elemAddr){
    void *source = (char *)s->elems + (s->lenght-1) * s->sizeOfElems;
    memcpy(elemAddr, source, s->sizeOfElems);
    s->lenght -=1;
}
int main(){
    stack s;
    allocate_stack(&s, 1);
    char a = 'a';
    push_elem(&s, &a);
    char *elem = NULL;
    pop_elem(&s, elem);
    printf("%s", elem);
    deallocate_stack(&s);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I don't get anything when I run the program, just press return to close the window. I'm programming on Linux using GCC toolkit.

Comment: I'm still scanning your program, but my first thought is that you're not checking for a null `s` in your `allocate_stack()` function.

Comment: I don't need to, s is declared in stack, only elems are in heap.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you're declaring `stack *s = NULL;` in `main()` (in other words, `s` is a null pointer), and then you're passing that null pointer to `allocate_stack()`, which promptly tries to dereference this pointer. Running your code as-is (though granted I'm on W7 using Visual Studio) results in a near-immediate program crash on the line `s->sizeOfElems = sizeOfElements;`, right as the first dereference happens. It's entirely possible that I'm misunderstanding something here though, so maybe you could set me straight.

Comment: Another comment: I'm guessing that you've come to C fairly recently, perhaps from the world of Python, as your `if` statement within `push_elem()` likely does not do what you want it to do. You should probably enclose the entire body of the `if` statement in `{...}` curly braces.

Comment: My programming background involve Python, but this isn't my first language, the if statement was typo. This was just a test, I mean that I tried stack *s = NULL, because  declaring just stack s didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your push_elem:

```
    s->lenght += 1;
    if(s->allocated == s->lenght){
        realloc(s, s->lenght * s->sizeOfElems);
        s->lenght *= 2;
    }
```

It seems like you are trying to re-allocate space if you run out, but your default value of 2 for allocated is going to stay as it is, you should probably do something like:

```
    if (s->allocated < s->lenght) {
        realloc(s->elems, ....)
        //Increase both allocated and length to represent the current state of the stack
    }
```

Notice that in the realloc() call you are passing s, which is in the stack, this won't do what you want:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/realloc.html
As per your structure you should be passing 
        s->elems

Also, before calling pop_elem, you are assigning NULL to elem. Inside your pop_elem, this is where you are trying to do a memcpy() to. To do this you will have to allocate memory:http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the allocation of your stack struct. When you do `allocate_stack` you must call allocate to create a stack object before assigning things to it. For instance the s you pass in is null and you start trying to assign values to the various fields of it. This is undefined behavior and likely the reason your program isn't working.

Try changing the signature of your allocate_stack function to return a stack pointer and then the first step should be to `malloc(sizeof struct stack)` . You should return the pointer you got from the malloc at the and and assign it to s.

Edit: unless you want the stack to be on the stack in which case allocate it like you would a normal variable.

Comment: My idea was the stack to be allocated in the stack not in the heap, only the elems(part from the struct) to be allocated in heap. But I change the stack s declaration in main func, and allocate s in the heap, I got the same result.

Comment: Ok you never actually create one then you just create a pointer. To do that you would have to do stack s; instead of stack *s; see this question       https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=7D3mU6nyHYfyoASE-oGoCA&url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916799/how-to-create-a-struct-on-the-stack-in-c&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNG33YcqSroVr5jsp9VyC7itulihhA&sig2=IQ-1nEWukHpnQUJKm0K8Eg

Comment: Well what happened, saying it didn't work doesn't help anyone help you. The community isn't here to write your code for you, give an error message at least.

Comment: I don't get any error message, I get only "press .... to return" from xterm, my debugger is broken(no idea why). I'm using QT creator as IDE, and gcc toolkit, I'm running on debain wheezy x86.

Comment: Try updating your original question with your new code

Comment: Looking at your original code it appears as though there are a lot of missed assignments for instance elem never gets assigned to anything, when you pass a pointer to a function it receives a copy of it. Your pointer elem is pointing to null, this doesn't change before you try to print it because you never assign the pointer to a different location.

Comment: Allocate stack func:
s->elems = malloc(sizeOfElements * s->allocated);
push func:
memcpy(target, elem, s->sizeOfElems);