# Declaring a struct on the stack

Tags: c, struct

This is from Zed Shaw's Learn C the Hard Way:

```
#define MAX_DATA 15
#define MAX_ROWS 100


struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char name[MAX_DATA];
    char email[MAX_DATA];
};

struct Database {
    struct Address rows[MAX_ROWS];
};

struct Connection {
    FILE *file;
    struct Database *db;
};


void Database_create(struct Connection *conn)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {

        struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0};

        conn->db->rows[i] = addr;
    }
}
```

For the line `struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0}`, we're declaring addr on the stack, and we're assigning that struct to `conn->db->rows[i]`. Before calling database_create(), I've initialized `conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));`

Once the function exits, addr gets cleaned up since it was on the stack. How does the value of `addr` persist inside `conn->db->rows[i]`? Is the assignment creating a copy of the data stored in `addr` and storing it on the heap location of `conn->db->rows[i]`?

Thanks!

Comment: It is copied (i.e., "by value") into `conn->db->rows[i]`.

Comment: "we're declaring addr on the stack" No guarantees for that in C. "How does the value of addr persist" You allocated a `struct Database` and wrote to it. It persists because `malloc`ated memory persists until `free`d.

Comment: @Rhymoid when i declare a variable inside a function (without calling malloc), its not guaranteed to be stored on the stack? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916799/how-to-create-a-struct-on-the-stack-in-c

Comment: @user2635088: The C-language standard does not dictate which memory segments a variable must be allocated in. It is platform (compiler/linker) dependent. It is true, however, that most (or even all) common implementations allocate non-static local variables on the stack, global and or/static variables in the data-section, and runtime memory blocks in the heap.

Comment: @barakmanos when you talk about implementations of c, does this refer to the compiler-ISA combination? I.e for my machine it would be gcc and x86_64?

Comment: @user2635088: I don't think that this issue is HW-dependent in any manner. Only build-tool-dependent (i.e. depends on compiler and/or linker implementation).

Comment: @barakmanos right, my comment was asking about the general case - I see everywhere people saying things like "the c language standard doesn't dictate X, so its up to the implementation". Implementation in this case refers to the compiler-ISA combination? Or something else? Sorry C noob here

Comment: @user2635088: Implementation of the compiler, yes (not sure what "ISA combination" means).

Comment: @barakmanos Ok. I meant the compiler prepares assembly code for a particular instruction set architecture, which is the instructions that the hardware understands, right? So the same compiler would emit different assembly instructions for a 32bit vs 64bit architecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a copy assignment.

In this case, you have an array of structures, which size equals to `MAX_ROWS*sizeof(struct Address)`. So, there is plenty of space in it anyway.

Consider the following:

```
struct coord{int x,y;};
struct coord a = {0,0};
struct coord b;
b = a; //This is a copy assignment
```

Here, each row of the array holds a complete structure, and you copy the value of `addr` inside.

---

What would not be a copy assignment would be an array of pointers:

```
struct Database {
    struct Address *rows[MAX_ROWS];
};
```

And after, `conn->db->rows[i] = &addr;`

Obviously, you would run into problems in this situation, as the values referenced by the pointers are undefined, and the different rows are highly likely to contain the same address. But this would be fine if you were using dynamic allocation.

You could try to display `sizeof(*(conn->db))` or `sizeof(conn->db->rows)` in both cases, if you want to see the fact that the array really holds `MAX_ROWS` structures when not using pointers.